# Vis DataSet via AJAX result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, vis.js

I am using [visjs timeline](http://visjs.org/index.html#modules) to make a timeline and I have a button that redraws that timeline on click event. The redrawing is done by getting data from timeline.php using AJAX but the data received doesn't work in DataSet!

Here is what I've got so far:

The function that is triggered when I click on button:

```
function redrawTL(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "ajax/timeline.php", data: {},
        success: function(data){
            redraw(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The function that should redraw the timeline assuming I already have set the variables items and tl

```
function redraw(data){
    console.log(data);
    items = new vis.DataSet([ data ]); // This doesn't!!
    tl.destroy();
    tl = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
}
```

So my question is why it doesn't work?! Knowing that the data is shown in console.

Data is supposed to be filled with the following data:

```
{id: 0, content: '07:10:12',   start: today.clone().add(25606, 'seconds'), 'className': 'tmstyle'}, 
{id: 1, content: '00:40:06',   start: today.clone().add(56563, 'seconds'), 'className': 'arretNU'}, 
{id: 2, content: '00:01:07',   start: today.clone().add(63312, 'seconds'), 'className': 'arretNU'}, 
{id: 3, content: '00:00:16',   start: today.clone().add(63389, 'seconds'), 'className': 'arretNU'}
```

And if I make the redraw function static it works fine.

Comment: Have you checked, whether the returned data is in the right format?
    items = new vis.DataSet([ data ]);
might result in an array within the array.
Maybe the success function is not called as well, to make sure the AJAX request is not failing try to change it to:
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "ajax/timeline.php", data: {},
        success: function(data){
            redraw(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(textStatus);   
        }
});

Comment: totally forgot about that post, i've solved it mate, i'll post the solution above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one day of trying i finally came up with the following solution:

```
            function redrawTL(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",url: "ajax/timeline.php", data: {},
                    success: function(data){
                        var result = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
                        items.clear();
                        items.add(result);
                        timeline.fit();
                    }
                });
            }
```

It works only if i use JSON.parse over another one!